Azure Functions error after upgrading to "isolated" instead of "in process": Error building configuration in an external startup class
I ran into this error when upgrading from an older version of .NET Core where functions ran "in process" to .NET 8 "isolated" instead of in-process. The details of this error were:
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.HostInitializationException : Referenced bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle of version 1.8.1 does not meet the required minimum version of 2.6.1. Update your extension bundle reference in host.json to reference 2.6.1 or later.
I tried several things including clearing out the "AzureFunctionDiagnosticEventsYYYYMM" table and adding a section in host.config for the correct extensions bundle, but nothing worked.

After much trial and error, I found it was 2 legacy environment variables on my functions app which caused this error. I had the variables "AzureWebJobStorage" and "AzureWebJobsDashboard"added as environment variables to my functions app. Removing these variables resolved my issue.

Hello. We are facing the same issue, but are hesitant with replacing AzureWebJobsStorage. Where can we see that it is legacy?
Are you saying that the problem would disappear if one is connecting to host storage with identity, instead of using AzureWebJobsStorage?
Currently looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage

TLDR: Delete file in storage-account in file share at
< app-name > -> site -> wwwroot -> host.json
We faced the same issue and found that the problem was that an old host.json-file persisted in the storage account. It included the extension bundle version 1-2 that is mentioned in the error message.
The file was located in the storage account in a file share at
< app-name > -> site -> wwwroot -> host.json
It seems it can not be found in kudu as it is probably overwritten there.
Deleting the file and re-deploying the application solved the issue.
